Near-Duplicate Image Detection in Java. Performance Problems
I am trying to prevent near-duplicate images in my system. But I need to check each incoming image against all existing ones. So it is not 1-1 similarity check. And sometimes images are not the same but almost identical. For example see these 2 images (note the slight brightness difference):

https://pbs.twimg.com/amplify_video_thumb/1864293853525684224/img/Xj98d6CgNDezU3SE.jpg
https://pbs.twimg.com/amplify_video_thumb/1864298609203671040/img/LxQ6a9wx9npYpGAQ.jpg

Therefore I tried to generate hash from the image which is stored in database and each incoming image is checked against database.
I implemented a solution in Java and which works fine but it consumes too much CPU. I am running it on 8CPU droplet and expected process rate is 100 reqs/second. But current solution reaches 100% CPU usage with 30-40 req/second and is not acceptable.
Do you have any suggestion for simpler process or should I create a separate service in Python to process image hash?
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class ImageUtil {
    private static final int HASH_SIZE = 16;
    private static final int INNER_SIZE = 8;
    private static final int OFFSET = 4;

    public static List<ImageHash> computeHashesBatch(List<String> urls) {
        return urls.parallelStream()
                .map(url -> {
                    try {
                        return new ImageHash(url, computePerceptualHash(url));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static String computePerceptualHash(String url) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(URI.create(url).toURL());
        if (img == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String hash = computeHashFromImage(img);
        return String.format("%s%s%s-%s", img.getType(), img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), hash);
    }

    private static String computeHashFromImage(BufferedImage img) {
        // Convert and resize
        BufferedImage processed = new BufferedImage(HASH_SIZE, HASH_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        Graphics2D g = processed.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, HASH_SIZE, HASH_SIZE, null);
        g.dispose();

        byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) processed.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        char[] hashBits = new char[INNER_SIZE * INNER_SIZE];
        int hashIdx = 0;
        long totalGradient = 0;

        for (int y = OFFSET; y < OFFSET + INNER_SIZE; y++) {
            int rowOffset = y * HASH_SIZE;
            for (int x = OFFSET; x < OFFSET + INNER_SIZE; x++) {
                int idx = rowOffset + x;
                int gx = (pixels[idx + 1] & 0xFF) - (pixels[idx - 1] & 0xFF);
                int gy = (pixels[idx + HASH_SIZE] & 0xFF) - (pixels[idx - HASH_SIZE] & 0xFF);
                int gradient = Math.abs(gx) + Math.abs(gy);
                totalGradient += gradient;
                hashBits[hashIdx++] = (char) gradient;
            }
        }

        int avgGradient = (int) (totalGradient / (INNER_SIZE * INNER_SIZE));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(16);
        int accumulator = 0;
        int bitCount = 0;

        for (char hashBit : hashBits) {
            accumulator = (accumulator << 1) | (hashBit > avgGradient ? 1 : 0);
            bitCount++;

            if (bitCount == 4) {
                result.append(Integer.toHexString(accumulator));
                accumulator = 0;
                bitCount = 0;
            }
        }

        if (bitCount > 0) {
            accumulator <<= (4 - bitCount);
            result.append(Integer.toHexString(accumulator));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    @Getter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class ImageHash {
        private String url;
        private String hash;
    }
}

Test code
    @Test
    void test() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<String> urls = Arrays.asList(
                "https://pbs.twimg.com/amplify_video_thumb/1864293853525684224/img/Xj98d6CgNDezU3SE.jpg",
                "https://pbs.twimg.com/amplify_video_thumb/1864298609203671040/img/LxQ6a9wx9npYpGAQ.jpg"
        );

        List<ImageUtil.ImageHash> hashes = ImageUtil.computeHashesBatch(urls);
        hashes.forEach(h -> log.info("{} - {}", h.getHash(), h.getUrl()));

        log.info("Duration: {}ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }


I'm not so sure that this algorithm will work at any speed.   I'd make it work before I worried about performance.  Chunking and parallelization might help.

the code works fine and I added a unit test to check that. It produces same 56751200-f9ee3bf0f6230080 hash value for both images

profile your code. know (and tell us) which parts take how long to execute. most trivial decomposition I can identify: the hashing, and then the query/lookup. -- never expect anyone to run your code. especially not if it's not a [mre]

I don’t know anything about Java, but your function computeHashFromImage() seems to render the image and then immediately destroy the render? What is that for? And then there’s a double loop that goes over a 8x8 square of pixels offset 4 pixels from the edge, it is reading only a tiny, fixed area of the image, and assumes the image is large enough. That makes no sense. Is g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, HASH_SIZE, HASH_SIZE, null) somehow modifying the img object? That doesn’t make much sense, that can’t be true! But if it were, [continued]

[continued] But if it were, it would be downsampling the image by a lot, and you’d have a lot of aliasing. You can’t compute gradients in such an image, they would be meaningless.

You should profile each step and focus on one issue here (or try code review instead). I've found that ImageIO library reading directly from url is not as quick as loading to local SSD/memory then reading.

I'm not so certain that the hash you end up with is a good measure of near duplication.  That's my objection.   Your hashing function might be doing exactly what it asked you to do, but the end result might not be what you have in mind.  Good luck.
